# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] at website connection

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, hosting

I have a website in AwardSpace for free hosting, linked through FTP to FileZila, and everything seems to be working fine, except for when I try to log in in the system and that requires a connection with the database in phpmyAdmin, I'm getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused' in /srv/disk3/2577376/www/integra.dx.am/entraradmin.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk3/2577376/www/integra.dx.am/entraradmin.php(4): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=inte...', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in /srv/disk3/2577376/www/integra.dx.am/entraradmin.php on line 4
```

The site was working fine when I was using it at localhost, and the PDO is:

```
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=integra.dx.am;dbname=sistemaintegra;charset=utf8","root","");
```

Note that I've changed the host from **localhost** to the AwardSpace host, but that didn't solve the problem. I'm using MySql in phpMyAdmi, and I have Wamp Server as my localhost, which seems to also contain my phpmyAdmin.

Any help?

Comment: are you trying to connect from localhost to remote server or this sample of code throws error when ran on server as well? btw. if you've changed host, you should probably update user privileges

Comment: The localhost works fine but when I try to connect from the server it gets that error. And the site already has 3 levels of privileges, but all the logins are failing.

Comment: Looks like permission errors for me... did you try to add new user to server via phpmyadmin on server or through command line and try with new user? as well do you have access to server via ssh console?